# Symfony table entity has itself recognized as repository as well

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

New to both Symfony and StackOverflow as an OP.

I'm on a way adding new mysql table entities and repositories on Symfony(4.3.2) and get stuck as I test it.
I really appreciate someone's help.

The error I got was

```
[2020-07-13 03:25:59] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "The "App\Entity\Foo" entity has a repositoryClass set to "App\Repository\Foo", but this is not a valid class. Check your class naming. If this is meant to be a service id, make sure this service exists and is tagged with "doctrine.repository_service"." at /var/www/html/bar_project/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Repository/ContainerRepositoryFactory.php line 66 {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): The \"App\\Entity\\Foo\" entity has a repositoryClass set to \"App\\Repository\\Foo\", but this is not a valid class. Check your class naming. If this is meant to be a service id, make sure this service exists and is tagged with \"doctrine.repository_service\". at /var/www/html/bar_project/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Repository/ContainerRepositoryFactory.php:66)"} []
```

where `Foo` at /App/Entity/ is an entity for the table `foo`.
and the problem is that it tries to refer to `Foo` at App/Repository/ as its repository which doesn't exist, but not `FooRepository` which exists.
(Updated this paragraph following the comment from `Jakumi`)

```
(FooController.php)

$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Foo::class);
```

```
(Foo.php)

<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FooRepository") // *1
 */
class Foo
{
...
```

```
(FooRepository.php)

<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Foo;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

/**
 * @method Foo|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * ...
 */
class FooRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
...
```

One thing I find mysterious is that the same error log still shows up even if I remove `*1`.
(I think I have yarn watch and cache clear appropriately working.)

---

Additional Info 1

```
(doctrine.yaml)

doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '8.0'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
        # dbname:
        # host:
        # port:
        # user:
        # password:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        options:
          1002: 'SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY", ""))'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        metadata_cache_driver: apcu
        result_cache_driver: apcu
        query_cache_driver: apcu
        connection: ~
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
        dql:
          string_functions:
            group_concat: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\GroupConcat
            date_format: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\DateFormat
```

Comment: the default question, have you cleared the cache?  have you created the entity/repository via `bin/console make:entity`? (it creates a repository as well by default) comment: entity hasn't itself recognized as repository, classname is App\Repository\Foo and not ..\Entity\ the `*1` is ignored because it's outside the `()` of the annotation

Comment: `repositoryClass=FooRepository::class` works (without quotes), if you have `use App\Repository\FooRepository;`. works in my symfony 5 installation.

Comment: -- have you ~ cache?
sure.

-- have you ~ via bin/console make:entity?
I haven't. tried this method and recreated the entity and the repository.

-- entity hasn't ......\Entity\
You are correct. It somehow tries to look up the Repository with the same base name to Entity's, but in the different package, which doesn't exist.

-- *1 is ignored ~ annotation
I meant removing the whole line. Indeed a strange try, but I was curious if the trouble came with the repository declared there.

Comment: -- repositoryClass=FooRepository::class works (without quotes), if you have use App\Repository\FooRepository;  
Thanks for the knowledge!

Comment: After practicing 1. recreating Entity&Repository using `bin/console make:entity` and 2. declaring the Repository from the Entity by means of the way without parenthesis following your comment, the exact same error message somehow still shows up. But thanks for your help!

Comment: that sounds really weird. the default should be `App\Repository\{entityname}Repository`. would you share your doctrine config?

Comment: indeed weird. This time, the handling got required because of some new db tables added, which means entity-repository pairs for other tables are still working fine. (added doctrine.yml on description.)

Comment: okay, under the assumption that you don't have some custom stuff writing to / reading from `[symfony]/var` (or var/cache), would you delete the var directory and try again? yes, this is desperation. maybe for some reason the code generation that works with annotations for some reasons doesn't update the information for some reason.

Comment: really appreciate the way that thoroughly clears the cache.  Though, the issue still remains. I'm beginning to suspect other factors like bad schema design of myself. Will repeat the trial-and-errors to see if I get something I can report here.